# Does declaring an unnecessary variable in PHP consumes memory?

Tags: php, performance, variables

I usually do this in PHP for better readability but I don't know if it consumes memory or has any other issues? Let's say I have this code:

```
$user = getUser(); // getUser() will return an array
```

I could do:

```
$email = $user["email"];
sendEmail($email);
```

Without declaring the variable $email I could do:

```
sendEmail($user["email"]);
```

Which one is better? Consider that this is just a very simple example.

Comment: Of course it consumes memory... but generally readability is more important than memory usage

Comment: @MarkBaker: I completely agree with you. But with all due respect, i would also like to mention that this also makes things clearer. Yes it consumes memory but the amount of memory it consumes is very very less as compared to the amount of clearity it provides. Luis clearly mentions that this is just a small example. Means the application is big. By using little more memory, if code gives better clarity, i wont mind defining some variables as the case mentioned by Luis. I would love to read from you too.

Comment: @DevangRathod Seriously? If you care about every single CPU cycle, you should not use PHP at all. Also a PHP script does not run in the browser. With all respect, it looks like you have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: If the application is consuming a lot of memory, then Luis really needs to identify exactly where the memory is being consumed, not simply look to save a little here and there that will probably be freed up anyway when out of scope

Comment: @fab ya right you are right i made an mistake

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'm not talking about an specific application, the code provided is not really being used, but I do this readability thing in pretty much everything I code. I was just wondering if this way to code has more impact than the value it provides having "human" variables.

Comment: It is not relevant, as the chances are that internally your code will be optimized by the interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't make your code less readable just to save a few bytes. And this will not save you more, even if `$email` is a 100 MB string, because internally PHP uses the **copy on write** mechanism: The *content* of a variable is not copied unless you change it.

Example:

```
$a = str_repeat('x', 100000000); // Memory used ~ 100 MB
$b = $a;                         // Memory used ~ 100 MB
$b = $b . 'x';                   // Memory used ~ 200 MB
```

Comment: Is that right? A [Quora engineer's answer](https://www.quora.com/Does-declaring-an-unnecessary-variable-in-PHP-consume-memory/answer/Jelle-Zijlstra) seems to contradict this....

Comment: I don't know what a "Quora engineer" is, but all that he states is that each variable has a memory overhead of around 140 byte, regardless the data. This doesn't contradict my point at all.

Comment: It's just that the second "~100 MB" is about 140 Bytes more than the first "~100 MB" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

yeah it is! Variable creates storage area so that you can use and manipulate them. if it is unused in that case the storage consumption will happen. `sendEmail($user["email"]);` would be a better way. but its not a good way to write codes without variables. Through variable you can track down the actual errors if there is any & it also helps in scalability,readability.