# Is it necessary to put a value into a variable?

Tags: php, algorithm

I have been asked about this simple question by a student and I was greatly troubled because I cannot provide a sufficient answer to this. What I understood is that, a variable is just a container that holds a value. Aside from that, I cannot provide a logical explanation to them.

example:

I want to check if an age is minor or not. By using a variable, I will make it this way:

```
<?php 
$age = 30;
if( $age > 18)
   echo 'You are no longer a minor';
?>
```

But, without using a variable, I can make it this way:

```
<?php  
if( 30 > 18)
   echo 'You are no longer a minor';
?>
```

If the two scripts produce the same output, then why should we put it in a variable, for in fact, we can lessen the code of we'll not use a variable. And also, Is it necessary to put a value into a variable?

Does it affect the memory of a computer?

Comment: The point of variables is that they hold a *changing* value. If the value of `$age` is a constant, what's the point of checking `$age > 18` when the check is always true?

Comment: Exactly what JJJ said, using constants you could shorten you code further as there would be no need for a check. You know already that 30 is less than 18 so you can simply run your echo. A logical explanation to your answer is simple, you cannot assume the age will always be 30, its value is variable and as such is stored in one, The code snippet doesnt help, but eventually the age will be pulled from a user account etc etc rather than just being set.

Comment: @samuel see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520237/does-declaring-an-unnecessary-variable-in-php-consumes-memory

Answer (score 2):

It's true that a variable is a container that "holds" a value, but its power comes when the value that variable holds varies between different executions of your code.

In the example provided by the OP, $age is hardcoded to 30 so there is no benefit to storing it in a variable for later comparison.

However, this slightly contrived example is unlikely to be found in real life. Instead the page would likely prompt the user for their age and then assign the response to the variable $age.

The same code would execute for each end user and depending on their responses the page would respond that they are no longer a minor, or it would remain silent.

For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$age = (int)readline("How old are you?"); // Prompt for a string and convert it to an integer
if( $age > 18)
     echo 'You are no longer a minor';
?>
```

Which responds thus:

```
$ ./askage.php
How old are you?30
You are no longer a minor
$ ./askage.php
How old are you?12
$
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that age in any valid usage will come from some form of input (user input, database select, webservice call etc) which would be stored in a variable in order to proceed with the rest of the logic. Your example here tries to falsify the input by setting the variable to a predefined value, which is all cool and dandy for examples, but in normal situations you would read that value from somewhere, hence the variable

Answer (score 1):

Variables are *placeholders* in an *algorithm*. Take the stereotypical mathematical case of "solving for X". X here is part of an algorithm, but you don't know the exact value of X and/or the result of the algorithm changes when you substitute different values for X. The same applies to programming:

```
if (30 > 18)
```

Well, okay, this code certainly does *something*, but what it does is predetermined. `30` will always be greater than `18`, so what's the point of writing this statement? You can just leave it out.

```
if ($age > 18)
```

This now introduces a *variable* whose value is determined elsewhere, and this algorithm will produce a different outcome depending on the specific value of `$age` as you run it. If you just hardcode the value of `$age` as well… well, that's not terribly interesting either, but presumably in the real world the value of `$age` will be determined at runtime by some external factor.

Answer (score 0):

In application and program using a any variable is totally depend on nature of your algorithm, if input which you receive to your application is dynamic in nature then its better to use variable but if input static & will remain same for each iteration then you can directly assign it to your logic.

Bellow are scenarios where you need variable and where you don't need variables, there are lots of scenario I am sharing which we use in daily life.

Where we need variable.

- To compare input data with any relevant data or previous input.
- Result calculation on input data.
- Modification on input data for any business case.

Where we don't need variable.

- To compare any static data, which pre-declare in program.
- Initiated any logic with definite value.
- Required limited or specific amount of iteration.

This is common among most of languages/scripts and hope this will help to understand the use cases for variable.